# Imap mail with php

Tags: php, imap

I am writing a mail client with IMAP/PHP . But how can I search mails wchich has attachement. There is no option with imap_search()

Answer (score 2):

In Imap/php have one option imap_fetchstructure it give part type of mail

```
            $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $messageNumber);
            $flattenedParts = $this->flattenParts($structure->parts);

            foreach($flattenedParts as $partNumber => $part)
            {
                switch($part->type)
                {

                case 0:
                    // the HTML or plain text part of the email
                    // now do something with the message, e.g. render it
                break;

                case 1:
                    // multi-part headers, can ignore

                break;
                case 2:
                    // attached message headers, can ignore
                break;

                case 3: // application
                case 4: // audio
                    break;
                case 5: // image

                    //break;
                case 6: // video
                case 7: // other

                       echo "Mail contain attachment ";
                        // don't know what it is
                    }
                    break;

                }
            }

           function flattenParts ($messageParts,$flattenedParts=array(),$prefix='', $index = 1, $fullPrefix=true) 
             {

    foreach($messageParts as $part) {
        $flattenedParts[$prefix.$index] = $part;
        if(isset($part->parts)) {
            if($part->type == 2) {
                $flattenedParts = $this->flattenParts($part->parts, $flattenedParts, $prefix.$index.'.', 0, false);
            }
            elseif($fullPrefix) {
                $flattenedParts = $this->flattenParts($part->parts, $flattenedParts, $prefix.$index.'.');
            }
            else {
                $flattenedParts = $this->flattenParts($part->parts, $flattenedParts, $prefix);
            }
            unset($flattenedParts[$prefix.$index]->parts);
        }
        $index++;
    }

    return $flattenedParts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, [IMAP SEARCH command specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) does not have an option to search for messages that contain attachments, it's not a PHP quirk. So you'll have to get a list of available messages in a certain mailbox, traverse them and check whether individual messages have attachments.